# BluePrism Reading data from excel datetime shifts

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, datatable, blueprism

> KeyWords: DataTable, DateTime, BluePrism
>   Situation: Reading data from excel file into datatable, datetime shifts.
>   Example: I have a simple excel file which contains table below:

```
ID | Date
1    03-07-2015
2    07-05-1998
3    11-11-1987
```

After reading excel file into c# **DataTable** using this method ([Read xls file to Import to DataTable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a4fae14-6764-4ccc-9781-845e3d035683/read-xls-file-to-import-to-datatable-but-no-need-to-install-any-com-component-dlls-etc-in-windows?forum=csharpgeneral) ) I get the following table:

```
ID | Date
1    2/7/2015 9:00:00 PM
2    6/5/1998 9:00:00 PM
3    10/11/1987 10:00:00 PM
```

**What i've tried:**

1. Reading excel file differently (no luck);
2. Finding out DataTable.Locale. When I run it on my c# console, locale is my computer's locale - **da-DK**. However, when I run the same function in code stage on Blue Prism, locale is changed to **en-US**. I've tried changing it to **da-DK** in BluePrism, but datetime parsing is not impacted.

When I import excel using only c#, it works fine. However, it does not when I run exact same code on Blue Prism. I understand that when string is being converted into Datetime, it is set as `date 00:00:00 <PM|AM>.` 
Why along the way subtraction happens is beyond me.

Comment: Timezone differences.

Comment: Did you try the build in bo to read ms excel file into collection?

Comment: Yeah, I did. The BO's action is made using the method which I linked in the question. The time difference happens only when I run the code on Blue Prism as mentioned, while in C# DateTime converts smoothly.

Comment: It's a Blue Prism feature/bug, as Vesnog answered. It's fixed in BP6.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are running the Blue Prism object on a computer with the local time set to UTC +3. Blue Prism always converts datetime variables retrieved via various channels into UTC values; therefore it subtracts 3 hours from the original entries. These channels may be MS Excel, SQL query, text file etc.

It becomes especially problematic if you store a datetime variable in a file use it store it back and call it again. Then Blue Prism will perform consecutive subtractions. The best way to deal with this is add **LocalTime() - UTCTime()** to every **datetime** item at the moment you retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was solve using CStr function, it retains the original value from the excel file.

Example:

```
Select CStr([Start Pay period]) as [Start Pay Period] From [Worksheet$]
```